# How to free the space on GPU?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, h2o, h2o4gpu

I am processing my model on a very large data set (of size about 1TB) by breaking it into chunks and then run a prediction on each chunks and then append the result in a file.

After running on each chunk I have to free the memory of GPU so that the other chunk can be processed and predicted.

Instead of running "Restart Kernel" again and again, I can run the loop if some command to clear the GPU memory exist.

Comment: Please mention what are you actually using (xgboost via h2o-3, some algorithms in h2o4gpu) and how (code samples).

Comment: Yes I am using xgboost.Random_forest_classifier of h2o4gpu

Comment: Each time i am running prediction memory is filled up , so my doubt is how to free that memory without restarting the kernel manually. @MateuszDymczyk

Comment: please provide a code sample and which version of h2o4gpu are you using. I just tried a simple test case and the memory seems to be automatically freed after predict.

Comment: Please can u share the code.

Comment: params = {'max_depth': 8, 'n_estimators': 100, 'tree_method': 'gpu_hist', 'n_gpus':1, 'backend':'h2o4gpu',
          'random_state': 123 , 'n_jobs': -1, 'predictor': 'gpu_predictor', 'verbose':1}
modelRF = h2o4gpu.solvers.xgboost.RandomForestClassifier(
    **params)
!sleep 5
modelRF.fit(X = (trainData[featureNames]), y = (trainData[dependentVar]))
t3=time.time()
a=modelRF.predict_proba(trainData[featureNames])
t4=time.time()

This is my code and the memory is not getting freed up automatically

Comment: by code I meant please provide an MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve we can run. Also if possible please provide output of `nvidia-smi` between predictions to show that the memory is actually increasing and not being freed.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810039/how-to-run-a-prediction-on-gpu here is my code